# SQL - Query to get db/table names and update statistics

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-job

I have a query which generate 'Update Statistics' queries for me which I then run manually.

I do something like:

```
select concat('Update statistics ',Database_Name,'.dbo.Table') from Dbinfo..Tables
```

I would like to automate this using a job.
What I have is:

```
declare @listdb as varchar(max)
set @listdb += @listdb (select concat('Update statistics ',Database_Name,'.dbo.Table') from Dbinfo..Tables)
```

Printing @listdb will return this result:

```
update statistics db1.dbo.Table;
update statistics db2.dbo.Table;
update statistics db3.dbo.Table;
```

The missing part is: How to I execute each generated line?

Comment: You have your question tagged with both sql-server (as in MSSQL) and plsql (as in Oracle). Judging by the syntax, it looks like sql-server. Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, i've changed it @BenThul

Answer (score 0):

You did the hard part which was creating the dynamic sql to run. All you need to do is execute the @listdb string like this.

```
exec sp_executesql @listdb
```

Comment: @DaleK they have all the statements in a string. Using a loop at this point would be foolish.

Comment: I wouldn't use dynamic SQL to do this - I would use a cursor (forward only) to loop over each item and perform the update.  This would allow for including additional checking and validation as well as error checking and logging of results.  For example, if the stats were just updated with a full scan in the past xx hours - do you really want to update them again with a sampling rate?

Comment: @Jeff that kind of checking can and should be put into the logic that builds the string. Using a cursor for this would just make it slower and provide no benefit. I mean it is just updating statistics. Nothing complicated or error prone there.

Comment: There are quite a few issues - and generating a string for potentially thousands of statistics to be updated will make identifying any of those issues virtually impossible.  I see this as one of those excessive dynamic queries used - just to avoid using a perfectly valid cursor.  How do you handle lock timeouts?  What about those stats just updated with a rebuild?  What about stats that were just auto updated - are you sure you want to repeat the update again?  Plenty of things to consider...

Comment: @Jeff while there are valid points on either side of this discussion the OP asked how they could run all the statements they stuck into a string. Simply executing would certainly solve that. Instead of stating all the reasons why the approach I posted is so bad perhaps you should consider posting your solution.